# loop optimization to escape hard coding

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 tables.
On every table, If I check a checkbox, they will automatically check all the following checkboxes. If i Uncheck said checkbox, it will uncheck all the following checkboxes. I wrote something that works well for one table, but I dont want to have to copy this code for every different table/range. Is there a way to optimize this code so I dont have to hardcode this for all the instances

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    
    If Range("A17") = TRUE Then
        For Each cell In Range("B19:B28")
            cell.Value = TRUE
            Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value = Now
            Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = VBA.Environ("Username")
        Next cell
    Else
        For Each cell In Range("B19:B28")
            cell.Value = FALSE
            Cells(cell.Row, "F").ClearContents
            Cells(cell.Row, "G").ClearContents
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Example :
IN RED : "cochez si non requis" is french for "check if not required"
[image]

EDIT:

I tried what @chris neilsen answered - and it's working, but the response time is way too slow. I feel like it's not optimized... This is the final code:

```
Sub SelectAll(rCheck As Range, rUpdate As Range, colTime As Long, colUser As Long)
    Dim cell        As Range
    
    If rCheck = TRUE Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="abc"
        For Each cell In rUpdate
            cell.Value = TRUE
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colTime).Value = Now
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colUser).Value = VBA.Environ("Username")
        Next cell
    Else
        For Each cell In rUpdate
            Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="abc"
            cell.Value = FALSE
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colTime).ClearContents
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colUser).ClearContents
        Next cell
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub

Sub SelectAll_Click()
    SelectAll Range("A17"), Range("B19:B28"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A31"), Range("B33:B35"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A38"), Range("B40:B41"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A45"), Range("B46:B49"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A52"), Range("B54:B62"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A66"), Range("B67:B72"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A75"), Range("B77:B83"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A86"), Range("B88:B89"), 6, 7
End Sub
```

Comment: Is one checkbook used to check all five tables or does each table have its own checkbox?

Comment: @Jimber every table has it's own checkbox !

Comment: Please see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalise your Sub by adding some parameters.

```vb
Sub SelectAll(rCheck As Range, rUpdate As Range, colTime As Long, colUser As Long)
    Dim cell As Range
    
    If rCheck = TRUE Then
        For Each cell In rUpdate 
            cell.Value = TRUE
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colTime).Value = Now
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colUser).Value = VBA.Environ("Username")
        Next cell
    Else
        For Each cell In rUpdate 
            cell.Value = FALSE
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colTime).ClearContents
            cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, colUser).ClearContents
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Call it in your Click event, passing the required parameters

```vb
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    SelectAll Range("A17"), Range("B19:B28"), 6, 7
End Sub
```

The above answer addresses the original question asked: *Is there a way to optimize this code so I dont have to hardcode this for all the instances*

To also address optimising speed, consider this

```vb
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="abc"

    SelectAll Range("A17"), Range("B19:B28"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A31"), Range("B33:B35"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A38"), Range("B40:B41"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A45"), Range("B46:B49"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A52"), Range("B54:B62"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A66"), Range("B67:B72"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A75"), Range("B77:B83"), 6, 7
    SelectAll Range("A86"), Range("B88:B89"), 6, 7

    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub

Sub SelectAll(rCheck As Range, rUpdate As Range, colTime As Long, colUser As Long)
    If rCheck = TRUE Then
        rUpdate.Value = TRUE
        rUpdate.EntireRow.Columns(colTime).Value = Now
        rUpdate.EntireRow.Columns(colUser).Value = VBA.Environ("Username")
    Else
        rUpdate.Value = FALSE
        rUpdate.EntireRow.Columns(colTime).ClearContents
        rUpdate.EntireRow.Columns(colUser).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, please see edited question!